# Failed to Install Umbraco CMS via Nuget Visual Studio 2012

Tags: umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco CMS, and I followed the tutorial from this site to install the umbraco cms in my visual studio.

> https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/install/install-umbraco-with-nuget

However I got this error

> Install-Package : Specified condition "$(WebProjectOutputDirInsideProject)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.  C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package UmbracoCMS
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidProjectFileException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Any idea how to solve this one? I use VS2012, .Net Framework 4.5, Nuget 2.8.6

Thanks to @JanR in the comment section disabled Resharper work for me. However when finish installing and try to run using F5 this error is happen.

Configuration Error :

```
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: are you using Resharper? There is a known issue where this messes with the installation : https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/55612-Error-installing-Umbraco-714-with-Nuget

Comment: Yup, I used Resharper 8. Thanks mate you solved my problem. Resharper is causing this error

Comment: That does not look like a configuration error, it is a line from your config. What is the error being reported?